# Does the WM_SIZE message get sent to the message queue?

Tags: c, winapi

When I resize my window and a `WM_SIZE` message is sent, does the `WM_SIZE` message get sent to the message queue or does the window procedure called directly?

Comment: That presumably depends on what method you use to resize it.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I mean when I resize the window using the mouse.

Comment: You should learn how to use tools like Spy++, they tell you this information.  Spy++ can monitor window messages and tell you which window they go to and if they are sent directly to the window or posted to the message queue.

Comment: @Remy the documentation for the message makes this clear

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I assume you are referring to this portion of the documentation: "*Sent to a window ... the DefWindowProc function sends the WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages to the window.*"

Comment: @Remy Yes, "sent to" is the key phrase.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I think you quoted your text from the comments section in the MSDN page. I think this is the text he was referring to: *"A window receives this message through its WindowProc function."*

Comment: @rony_t: Messages posted to the message queue are also delivered to a window through its WindowProc function. So that alone is not an indication of whether a message was sent or posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing a window by mouse sends `WM_SIZE` directly to the window procedure, it does not go through the message queue.